# Setting D3DImage to Image and Rendering in WPF

Tags: wpf, directx, directx-12

I would like to render to a surface using DX12 and present it through WPF. There are claims on the web that this is possible. To me it seems simple. I can render as a traditional image(ie tga) on hard drive, or some mapped memory, and then present that image through D3DImage--or simply an image brush in wpf. I would think the most straight forward approach would be to render to a DXGI surface, and then copy that over to a IDirect3DSurface9. I don't see how I can map from the source to the destination in any scenario--whether it be presenting a tga, or passing the rendered surface from dxgi to dx9. Microsoft's solution on GitHub is broken, and the part with the passing of the image is shrouded in darkness. Previous MS examples have been deleted, and codeproject has examples from last decade. I have no code to date because I don't know what to put into the relevant section. I have no real interest in using the managed solutions that are available.

Answer (score 1):

it seems i may have been a little impatient. the solution to my problem would seem to be ID3D##Device::OpenSharedResource(). when rendering, render to texture with CreateTexture() and pSharedHandle. this will allow the texture resource to be shared with d3d9. then i can consume the texture with a basic d3d9 pipeline that renders the texture to a basic rectangle in wpf through d3dimage. if i'm missing something let me know.